# Using selenium with python to comment on posts on Instagram but getting error "Element not interactable"

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

So basically, I'm using selenium to automate an instagram bot to comment on my friends posts to mess with them and to simply learn how to use selenium further.

I am using the driver.find_element_by_xpath for the username and password login just fine with the .send_keys() function but when I select the comment box and try to .send_keys() to it I recieve the aforementioned error. I assume this is a block by instagram to prevent this kind of behavior, but are there any workarounds?

```
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')\
             .send_keys(msg)
        sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please share html of element

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use `webdriver wait` so element get ready to interact. Please take locator (xpath) should be correct or share html so I can make locator.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea")))
element.send_keys(msg)
```